# suspend setInterval

Tags: javascript

I use setInterval to run a function (doing AJAX stuff) every few seconds. However I also have an other function also calling it.

```
setInterval(myFunc(), 5000);
function buttonClick() {
  // do some stuff
  myFunc();
}
```

Most of the time it works, however sometimes this function gets called twice at the same time resulting in receiving exactly the same result twice, something I don't want.

I think I have to use clearTimeout:

```
var interval = setInterval(myFunc(), 5000);
function buttonClick() {
  clearTImeout(interval);
  // do some stuff
  myFunc();
  interval = setInterval(myFunc(), 5000);
}
```

However this causes the function to halt. Since it gets called from an other function some code never gets executed. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Seems you want to put the result in one object that is accessible by anyone interested, so you can do a publish-subscribe idea and when you get a new value, push it out everywhere.  Your problem seems like design.

Comment: Do you mean `setInterval(myFunc, 5000);` without the `()`?

Comment: Example of how to prevent multiple-execution: http://jsfiddle.net/As56S/ (Excuse me using jQuery, but wanted outputting the data simple).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> however sometimes this function gets called twice at the same time resulting in receiving exactly the same result twice, something I don't want.

JavaScript on browsers is single-threaded (barring using the new [web workers](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/) stuff, but that wouldn't apply here anyway). Your function will never get called while it's running. (But more below.)

In your various code quotes, you're *calling* `myFunc` where you mean to just be referring to it. E.g.:

```
var interval = setInterval(myFunc(), 5000);
```

should be

```
var interval = setInterval(myFunc, 5000);
//                               ^--- No parentheses
```

Your code cancelling the timeout will work if you correct that:

```
var interval = setInterval(myFunc, 5000);
function buttonClick() {
  clearTImeout(interval);
  // do some stuff
  myFunc();
  interval = setInterval(myFunc, 5000);
}
```

But there's no reason to do that, `myFunc` cannot get called while it's running anyway.

If `myFunc` is *triggering* something that will complete asynchronously (an ajax call, for instance), the above **won't** help (for the simple reason that `myFunc` will start the process and then return; the process will complete separately). In that situation, your best bet is to have `myFunc` schedule its next call itself:

```
function myFunc() {
    // Do my work...

    // Schedule my next run
    setTimeout(myFunc, 5000);
}
```

...and not use `setInterval` at all.

Answer (score 0):

Unless `myFunc` returns a function I would do this (also use `clearInterval` in stead of `clearTimeout`):

```
var interval = setInterval(myFunc, 5000);
function buttonClick() {
  clearInterval(interval);
  // do some stuff
  myFunc();
  interval = setInterval(myFunc, 5000);
}
```

`setInterval` expects a function in its argument. You call a function by using `myFunc()`. so whatever is returned by `myFunc` was passed to `setInterval` which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I realize there's a couple of solutions already, but thought I'd show one that has a tad more than just "do this". I tend to learn by example, and thought I would extend the same practice. That being said, the [demo is here](http://jsfiddle.net/As56S/) but I'll try to explain as well.

```
// Here we assign the function to a variable that we can use as an argument to the
// setInterval method.
var work = function(){
    // performing a very simple action for the sake of demo
    $('#log').append('Executed.<br />');
};

// this is a variable that is essentially used to track if the interval is or is
// not already running. Before we start it, we check it. Before we end it, we also
// check it. Let's start off with it started though
var worker = setInterval(work, 5000);

// bind to the start button
$('#start').click(function(){
    // Test: is the worker already running?
    if (worker)
        // Yes it is, don't try to call it again
        $('#warn').text('Timer already running!');
    else{
        // no it's not, let's start it up using that function variable we declared
        // earlier
        worker = setInterval(work,3000);
        $('#warn').text('Started!');
    }
});

// bind to the stop button
$('#stop').click(function(){
    // test: is the worker running?
    if (!worker)
        // no, so we can't stop it
        $('#warn').text('Timer not running!');
    else{
        // yes it's working. Let's stop it and clear the variable.
        clearInterval(worker);
        worker = null;
        $('#warn').text('Stopped.');
    }
});
```